# IE8 Display: table child size

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

Hovering the div will trigger the mouse over effect on the child button.
Clicking on the div (outside) the button also triggers the buttons onMouseDown.

Example code:

```
<DIV style="DISPLAY: table; background-color:#F5DFE8; width:500px;">
    <button onMouseDown="alert('hello')";">Button</button>
</DIV>
```

A fiddle for testing it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/N2c8t/15/

Been googling my tail off, any known solution to this? Other than just not using display:table obviously. :) Thanks!

note: Tagged this with IE8 and IE9 as those are the browsers I have tried so far.

Comment: Weird. I looked at your fiddle with a few different browsers... FF, Chrome and Safari on the Mac and Chrome and FF on the PC did not exhibit this behavior.  I did see what you mean in IE8 though ... only thought I had was maybe trying z-index, but that didn't help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It almost seems like IE is treating the `button` as `display: table-row` no matter what actual `display` setting is put (and thus filling the whole div). Running interference with another element [solved it](http://jsfiddle.net/N2c8t/16/) (if this is a viable solution for you):

```
<DIV style="DISPLAY: table; background-color:#F5DFE8; width:500px;">
    <span><button onMouseDown="alert('hello');">Button</button></span>
</DIV>
```

**But perhaps better still** (less intrusive), *keeping your same original html* and adding a psuedo-element to the `div` also [solved it](http://jsfiddle.net/N2c8t/17/):

```
div:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
}
```

Comment: Turns out the display option in my code was unnecessary, so removing that fixed it (for me) hah. You are correct though, thank you for your answer! :-)